# How to set custom text when copying BlockUIContainer from FlowDocument to clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have flow document with embedded BlockUIContainers. I want to replace them with appropriate text when users copies text containing them to clipboard.

**Upadate:**
I have following chat interface:
[image: Chat]

Captions with time and username are done with `BlockUIContainer`s (I don't know how to do it using FlowDocument elements). When users selects some messages and copies them to clipboard, username and time are not copiet because they are TextBlocks. I want to intercept copy command and format chat text appropriately.

Comment: [BlockUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer.aspx) class is for placing other [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx#inheritanceContinued) objects (i.e. Button, ListBox, etc.) to be hosted in flow content, so it really depends on what exact text you're looking to extract from the BlockUIContainer.

Comment: I want to make some kind of converter that receives reference to BlockUIContainer and returns some text based on it.

Comment: The only problem is, how do you know the order of the UIElements within the BlockUIContainer?  Have you tried using a Table?

Comment: I know because I made this template myself. In fact, I will use it's DataContext object to extract all needed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with using dirty trick. Appended invisible paragraps near my container with text to copy:

```
<BlockUIContainer />
<Paragraph FontSize="0.1" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=document, Path=Background}" Margin="0">
    <Run Text="{Binding actualText}" />
</Paragraph>
```

Comment: All along I thought you were doing this so you could get the fancy borders and such around your text.

Comment: Yes, in my solution I place small invisible text *near* actual UI container. So if user selects whole message with caption he also selects invisible text that that represents caption content. There is also probability that user wants to select text without caption but selects invisible text, but odds are pretty low because font size is very small.

Comment: This is a really clever approach. I've been thinking about this for awhile and this never crossed my mind. Overriding ctrl+c is kind of hacky imo.

Answer (score 4):

That approach was very helpful Harlow, but hooking KeyUp to detect Ctrl+C will not detect contextmenu Right Click -> Copy events, but this does (and Ctrl+C also):

```
public YourWindowConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(flowDocumentReader1, CustomCopyCommand);
}

private void CustomCopyCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    e.CancelCommand(); //disable the default copy behavior that executes after this function returns

    // custom clipboard code here ...

    Clipboard.SetText("new text");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic way to manipulate what gets copied to the clipboard from a FlowDocumentReader.

The basic logic is, intercept CTRL+C with the FlowDocumentReader.KeyUp event, get the data that was just copied to the clipboard, modify it, then insert the modified data back to the clipboard.

```
private void flowDocumentReader1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for CTRL+C
    if (e.Key == Key.C && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        // Get clipboard information
        IDataObject clipboardDataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

        // Get list of available formats currently in clipboard
        string[] formatsInClipboard = clipboardDataObject.GetFormats();

        // Choose a format to use
        string desiredFormat = "Text"; // You can select Text, UnicodeText, Rich Text Format, etc.

        // Check for availability of desired format
        if (Array.IndexOf(formatsInClipboard, desiredFormat) >= 0)
        {
            // Get copied text
            string initialClipboardText = Clipboard.GetData(desiredFormat).ToString();

            // Update copied text
            string newClipboardText = InsertNameAndTimestamps(initialClipboardText);

            // Insert updated text to clipboard
            Clipboard.SetData(desiredFormat, newClipboardText);
        }                
    }
}

// Sample text modification, modify however you like
private string InsertNameAndTimestamps(string initialClipboardText)
{
    return "[MODIFIED TEXT]" + initialClipboardText + "[MODIFIED TEXT]";
}
```

This example is simplified by just wrapping the copied text in "[MODIFIED TEXT]" which makes it easy to see that it works by copying something in the FlowDocumentReader and then pasting it in Notepad.

It is also simplified by using plain text, but if you feel like mucking about with Rich Text Format, you have that option as well.

**Edit:**
If you are unable to determine what and where to insert into the copied text, you will have to process FlowDocumentReader.Selection manually (since the default copy behavior does not copy UIElements to the clipboard).

Assuming your FlowDocument looks like this:

```
<FlowDocumentReader xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="flowDocumentReader1" KeyUp="flowDocumentReader1_KeyUp">
    <FlowDocument>
        <BlockUIContainer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock>qwe</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right">00:15:37</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </BlockUIContainer>

        <Paragraph>Hi</Paragraph>

        <BlockUIContainer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Right">00:15:48</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </BlockUIContainer>

        <Paragraph>How are you?</Paragraph>

    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

You could process it like this:

```
private void flowDocumentReader1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check for CTRL+C
    if (e.Key == Key.C && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Prevent duplicate processing
        BlockUIContainer lastBlockUIContainer = null;

        // Get start of selection
        TextPointer currentPointer = flowDocumentReader1.Selection.Start;

        // Process selected text
        while (currentPointer != null && currentPointer.GetOffsetToPosition(flowDocumentReader1.Selection.End) > 0)
        {
            // Check for BlockUIContainer
            BlockUIContainer blockUIContainer = currentPointer.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Backward) as BlockUIContainer;
            if (blockUIContainer != null && blockUIContainer != lastBlockUIContainer)
            {
                // Get text from Grid
                Grid grid = blockUIContainer.Child as Grid;
                if (grid != null)
                {
                    string replacementText = String.Format("{0}\t{1}",
                        (grid.Children[0] as TextBlock).Text,
                        (grid.Children[1] as TextBlock).Text
                        );
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(replacementText);
                }

                // GetAdjacentElement can return the container from multiple TextPointers, so only process once
                lastBlockUIContainer = blockUIContainer;
            }
            else
            {
                // Get text at current position
                string text = currentPointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(text);
                }
            }

            // Move to next TextPointer
            currentPointer = currentPointer.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }

        // Insert updated text to clipboard
        string newClipboardText = stringBuilder.ToString();
        Clipboard.SetData("Text", newClipboardText);
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Nice approach but there is one problem: without references to my BlockUIContainers I don't know where and what to insert.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make some kind of converter that receives reference to
>   BlockUIContainer and returns some text based on it.

```
string GetBlockUIText(BlockUIContainer blockUIContainer)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    var line = blockUIContainer.Child as Panel;
    foreach (TextBlock child in line.Children)
    {
        s.Append(child.Text + " ");
    }
    return s.ToString();
}
```

To capture Ctrl+C:

```
KeyUp += (o, e) =>
{
    if (e.Handled == false)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
        {
            lastKeyWasCtrl = true;// lastKeyWasCtrl is field
            return;
        }
        if (lastKeyWasCtrl &&
            e.Key == Key.C)
        {// Ctrl+C pressed

        }
    }
};
```

Comment: heh, the problem is how to make that function apply to BlockUIContainers when user copies text?

Comment: That KeyUp handler is whack, it not only accepts `Ctrl, C` but also any string of inputs where `Ctrl` has been pressed before `C` because the field is never reset to false.

Comment: Aye, forgot an else to reset.